# How to fix maven warning about thread group still running when using GCSUtil to write files?

Tags: maven, google-cloud-dataflow

I wrote a simple [program](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/b2e666896b763e5b8293da899885ecdea31d45af/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/GCSRunningThreads.java?at=master) to write a text file to GCS using [GCSUtil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/GcsUtil.java)

I run the program using mvn:exec

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="dataflow.GCSRunningThreads" -Dexec.args=--output=gs://my-bucket/tmp/hello_world
```

Maven exits with the following error

```
[WARNING] thread Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,dataflow.GCSRunningThreads] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,dataflow.GCSRunningThreads] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 1 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=dataflow.GCSRunningThreads,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy(ThreadGroup.java:775)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This might have been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13471519/441652) by setting property `-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you need to shutdown the ExecutorService used by GcsUtil. The following snippet works:

```
GcsOptions gcsOptions = options.as(GcsOptions.class);
gcsOptions.getExecutorService().shutdown();
try {
  gcsOptions.getExecutorService().awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  sLogger.error("Thread was interrupted waiting for execution service to shutdown.");
}
```

GCSUtil uses an executor service to handle IO operations asynchronously. We need to shutdown that executor service in order to exit cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting below property in your pom (or pass it through command line).

```
cleanupDaemonThreads = false
```

Checkout this question,
[Running daemon with exec-maven-plugin avoiding `IllegalThreadStateException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471519/running-daemon-with-exec-maven-plugin)