# nanohttpd demo App crashed after 15seconds

Tags: java, maven, nanohttpd

I want to find a light http service for my Java program, and after research, I find [nanohttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) is so light with only one java page, and easy installation, so I want to wrap my Java program with this framework.

I have tried tutorial on nanohttpd github page, everything is ok, but for the final step,

```
    mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.App"
```

it crashed after about 15seconds with this info

```
[root@zhangruichang-test-dev001-shgq myHellopApp]# mvn exec:java -
Dexec.mainClass="com.example.App"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myHellopApp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ myHellopApp ---
ready to start

Running! Point your browers to http://localhost:8080/ 

[WARNING] thread Thread[NanoHttpd Main Listener,5,com.example.App] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[NanoHttpd Main Listener,5,com.example.App] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 1 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=com.example.App,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy(ThreadGroup.java:775)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.491s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 18 19:24:39 CST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/144M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I have googled it but without any most related issues.

I use 
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 21:51:28+0800) and OpenJDK with
Java version: 1.7.0_85, vendor: Oracle Corporation
on 
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
with CentOS 6.4.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a hint: you could change the "exec-maven-plugin" to tell it not to kill daemon threads.
Something such as:

```
<configuration>
       <mainClass>com.test.Startup</mainClass>
       <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
</configuration>
```

See here also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25166013/259988